# AUCTeX and XeTeX

Tags: xetex, emacs, auctex

I use Emacs+AUCTeX to write my *-tex. Using the PDF mode, I can run pdfTeX automatically with the `C-c C-c` command. However, I don't see a way to run XeTeX automatically, or even set up a command option in the drop down window. My LISP skills are very rusty, and I was wondering if someone had a `tex.el` patch to enable XeTeX support ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you have AUCTeX version 11.86, you can set the local variable `TeX-engine` to `xetex`. This is what I use:

```
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% coding: utf-8
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: xetex
%%% End:
```

You have to open the file again for the effect to take place (`C-x C-v`).

You can check the version you have with

```
C-h v AUCTeX-version <RET>
```

Comment: is there a relatively easy way to check the version of auctex I have ?

Comment: Where do we have to put those directives? inside tex files or...

Comment: @HarishKumar At the very end of the TeX file.

Comment: for some reason these directives didn't change the `TeX-engine` to `xetec` using Emacs24.4 on Windows7!

Comment: @doctorate The directives are read when you visit (open) the file. Close the file then open it again.

Comment: `GNU Emacs 25.3.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9)`. Tried the above but got no change in error. but CLOSING AND REOPENING WORKS.

Answer (score 21):

You can add this to your emacs.el:

```lisp
(setq-default TeX-engine 'xetex)
```

And add this if you want a PDF output by default:

```lisp
(setq-default TeX-PDF-mode t)
```

Comment: Personally, I'd enable PDF output globally (with your syntax) but I'd set the TeX engine locally.

Answer (score 16):

For versions 11.86 and higher,¹ there is also

```
M-x TeX-engine-set RET xetex RET
```

which will make AUCTeX compile that particular file with XeTeX (or `xelatex` if the file is considered a LaTeX file).  Note that this 'setting' will only continue to work so long as `emacs` is visiting that file.  Often useful if you forgot to set the local variables, or you want to quickly compare how different engines compile the same document.  Since PDFTeX can be much faster than other engines (esp. LuaTeX), I often use it while writing my documents, and only switch to LuaTeX in the final stage(s).  Resetting the Local Variables all the time is not ideal for that.

---

¹ Actually, I'm not sure when this command was added....

Answer (score 11):

You could customize the Tex Command List:

```
   M-x customize-variable TeX-command-list
```

There you can add a new commands to AUCTeX. Alternatively, you can directly modify your emacs init file:

```lisp
;; set XeTeX mode in TeX/LaTeX
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 
          (lambda()
             (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list '("XeLaTeX" "%`xelatex%(mode)%' %t" TeX-run-TeX nil t))
             (setq TeX-command-default "XeLaTeX")
             (setq TeX-save-query nil)
             (setq TeX-show-compilation t)))
```