# AUCTeX, preview-latex and Xelatex

Tags: xetex, emacs, auctex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AUCTeX and Xetex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21200/auctex-and-xetex)

sometimes I have to edit tex files with xelatex. Those files can be successfully compiled from the console. Auctex work fine with regular tex files and preview-latex can also generate previews.

Xelatex can't create .dvi files, but those are required to generate previews. Is there any workaround.

I would be satisfied if Auctex would automatically detect what xelatex compiler is needed. My knowledge of lisp isn't that grate at this time, so i need help.

I also tried to add an option in C-c C-c to call xelatex.

```
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
          '("XeLaTeX" "xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode %s" TeX-run-command t t :help "Run xelatex") t))
```

This code doesn't work for some reason and i get this error:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: TeX-command-list
```

Thank you!

Comment: N.N that thread doesn't cover my problem, i was looking into it before i posted.

Comment: I don't think there's any workaround: `preview` *really* needs a `dvi` file.