# Setting Emacs TeX-engine locally does not work

Tags: emacs

I'd like to follow the advice from @egreg in his answer to the question [AUCTeX and XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21200/auctex-and-xetex). However the given code does not work for me.

I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\section{title}

test

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% coding: utf-8
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% End:
```

but when I try to compile with `C - c` `C - c` I get the classic:

> fatal error, fontspec requires...

If I change the TeX-engine globally with `M - x` -> `customize-variable` ->  `TeX-engine` everything works fine.

I have emacs 24.4.1 and AUCTex 11.88

Comment: The change to the local variables is recognized only the next time the file is visited.

Comment: @egreg I see... Is there a way to force the reload or something similar without closing/reopening the file?

Comment: Go to the "Command>TeXing Options" menu and choose "Use LuaTeX engine"

Comment: well, that's it. I removed the menubar but this may be a reason to put it back. thanks

Comment: Or issue `C-c C-n`, this resets AUCTeX.

Comment: Emacs offers an on-demand popup-menu of the menu-bar stuff, and also offers a minibuffer navigation of the menubar stuff.  So, you can save screen real estate.

Answer (score 5):

The error pointed out in comment is that the file must be reload to change the local variable. 
Emacs permit to do it using `M-x revert-buffer` and answer `yes` to the confirmation.

Comment: Alternatively you can run `M-x normal-mode` on the buffer.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Or `M-x TeX-normal-mode`... Or `C-c C-n`...

Answer (score 2):

There is also the function `hack-local-variables`.  <kbd>C-h f hack-local-variables RET</kbd> says:

> hack-local-variables is a compiled Lisp function in `files.el'.
>
> (hack-local-variables &optional MODE-ONLY)
>
> Parse and put into effect this buffer's local variables spec. Uses
>   `hack-local-variables-apply' to apply the variables. [...]

<kbd>M-: (hack-local-variables) RET</kbd> in a buffer should do the trick.