# Can compile with luatex in the command line but not in AUCTEX in emacs

Tags: luatex, auctex

As stated in the title, my document compiles successfully with `lualatex file.tex` in the command line but not when in emacs using AUCTEX, executing `C-c C-c`. I'm using a Mac; Tex Live; and auctex v12.1.1.

I am aware of this answer:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21212/103829 and have inserted the following at the bottom of my .tex file:

```
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% coding: utf-8
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% End:
```

Comment: Does it work if you manually `M-x TeX-engine-set <ret>` and set it to `luatex`?

Comment: nope. doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: Then post a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and the log file which `C-c C-c` in Emacs created.

Comment: Here is the MWE: https://gist.github.com/oliverangelil/2bd2f3e5dc82ada84faaef05b6152c33. And here is the log file: https://gist.github.com/oliverangelil/381c881b9600a7373ac6bea793322506

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MWE is not like what you post, it contains:

```
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% coding: utf-8
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% TeX-master: ""
%%% End:
```

Remove the evil line with TeX-master. Or replace it with

```
%%% TeX-master: t
```

if needed.

Personnally I have had for decades

```
(setq TeX-one-master '"\"<none>\"")
```

in my `.emacs` to prevent AUCTeX modifying my file contents.

Comment: It could be that in the past AUCTeX did not have the default `t` setting for TeX-master which it seems to have now. I recall how painful it was at first when systematically my buffer ended up with some added lines for "Local Variables" at bottom, which got me really annoyed as I did not want to change modification date of a visited `.tex` file, typically.

Comment: In my case I needed the `%%% TeX-master: t` for it to work. But I added `(setq TeX-one-master '"\"<none>\"")` to my .emacs file to prevent annoying additions to the bottom of files!